# Legal use of creating a new object on a global namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would this be a legal use of creating an object on a global namespace? My goal is to create 1 global namespace for this application. Also how would I alias MYNYTE.app? Could I do something like this with out polluting the Global namespace:  **var b = MYNYTE.app;**

```
if( ! MYNYTE ) MYNYTE = {};
if( ! MYNYTE.app ) MYNYTE.app = {};


MYNYTE.app.Playbook = function(){

    this.change = '';
    this.boo = function(){alert('boo');}


    this.setChange = function( v )
    {
        this.change = v;    
    }

    this.getChange = function( v )
    {
        return this.change;
    }
}

var test    = new MYNYTE.app.Playbook();
var test2   = new MYNYTE.app.Playbook();

test.boo();
test.setChange( 'Change is bad' );
test2.boo();
test2.setChange( 'Change is great' );
console.log( test2.getChange() );
console.log( test.getChange() );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the structure I usually use. Interesting to see if there's something better!

```
var MYNYTE = MYNYTE || {};
MYNYTE.app = MYNYTE.app || {};

(function() {
    var Playbook = function Playbook() {
      ...
    };

    MYNYTE.app.Playbook = Playbook;
})();

// Avoid polluting the global scope
(function() {
    var b = MYNYTE.app.Playbook;
    var OtherClass = function OtherClass() {
      ...
      b.setChange( 'something' );
    };

    MYNYTE.app.OtherClass = OtherClass;
})();
```

Comment: I think that is right! Thanks for the quick response. This is how I now have it setup (see below). I am trying to write better JS and wanted to make sure I was doing it correctly. Thanks!


 if( ! MYNYTE ) MYNYTE = {};
 if( ! MYNYTE.app ) MYNYTE.app = {};
 
 ( function(){
  
  var PlaybookModel = function model()
  {
     
   
  } 
  
  MYNYTE.app.PlaybookModel = PlaybookModel;
 })() 
  
  
 ( function(){
 
 var PlaybookController = function Controller()
 {
    
  
 } 
 
 
 MYNYTE.app.PlaybookController = Controller;

})()

Comment: Looks nice! Just the last line should be MYNYTE.app.PlaybookController = PlaybookController;